# Is there a way to port this shell code to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I wanna automate the download of a specific file from a webserver this specific webserver unfortunately has no public API I could use but they published following shell script to download the file. My problem is I never worked with shell script before so I have no idea how I could port the shell code so it works in python. I have written a script that works with selenium to automate the task but I don't want to see the browser popping up every time I download a file. I already know how to use requests to download files but I don't really understand the "sed -n" part of the code. I appreciate any kind of help.
Shell code:

```
# Make sure the supplied URL looks valid
if [ "$(grep -Poc 'nopy.to\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\/(.*?)$' <<< $1)" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo -e " ! Error: Only nopy.to URLs are supported\n"
    exit 1
fi

# Parse the code and file from URL
code=`echo $1 | sed -n 's/.*nopy.to\/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{8\}\)\/.*/\1/p'`
file=`echo $1 | sed -n 's/.*nopy.to\/[a-zA-Z0-9]\{8\}\/\(.*\)\/\?/\1/p'`

# Fetch the session
echo -e " Fetching session ...\n"
sessionreq=`curl -s --data-urlencode "code=$code" --data-urlencode "file=$file" -X POST https://data.nopy.to/file`

if [ "$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.status')" != "ok" ]; then
    echo -e " ! Error: Session request failed\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.error_fatal')" != "false" ]; then
    echo -e " ! Error: Nopy is having technical issues\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -f "$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.filename')" ]; then
    echo -e " ! Error: File \"$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.filename')\" already exists\n"
    exit 1
fi

# Fetch the download URL
echo -e " Requesting download ticket ...\n"
downloadreq=`curl -s --data-urlencode "code=$code" --data-urlencode "fid=$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.fid')" --data-urlencode "request=$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.request')" --data-urlencode "session=$(echo $sessionreq | jq -r '.msg.session')" -X POST https://data.nopy.to/download`
```

Comment: Yes it can be done using "requests" module. If you want I can share my project code privately. I have made similar thing using requests.

Comment: @TanishqBanyal Sure I am open to anything if it can help. And thanks for offering this. How would you share it with me "privately"?

Comment: Ill just create an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that task using requests module.

I also made a similar script. It might help you :-

```
from __future__ import division
from tqdm import tqdm # for progress bar
import requests # for downloading

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = input('Enter URL : ')
 
buffer = 8000

# download the body of response by chunk, not immediately
response = requests.get(url,stream = True,verify = False)

# get the total file size
cl = response.headers.get("Content-Length")
if cl == None :
    file_size = None
else :
    file_size = int(cl)

# get the file name
name = input("Enter File Name :")
if name :
    filename = name
else :
    filename = url.split("/")[-1].split("?")[0]


def dl() :
    print("Download Size :",round(file_size/1048576,1),"MB")
    print()
    progress = tqdm(response.iter_content(buffer), f"Downloading {filename}", total=file_size, unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
           for data in progress:
            file.write(data)
            progress.update(len(data))

def fdl() :
    print("Download Size : Unknown (∞)")
# Someone edit the answer and complete this function. My one didn't work.

if file_size == None :
    fdl() # when Download size is unknown from header
else :
    dl() # when Download size is known from header

print("Downloading Finished !\n")
```